# why does my batch script says "missing operator"?

Tags: windows, batch-file, operator-keyword

I'm using this script:

```
@echo on
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\names.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    snmpwalk -v 2c -c root %%A .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2 > C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\cpu.txt
    snmpwalk -v 2c -c root %%A .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.2 > C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\ramvid.txt
    snmpwalk -v 2c -c root %%A .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.2 > C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\ram.txt
)

FOR /F "tokens=4" %%B IN (C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\ram.txt) DO echo %%B >> C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\ramfiltruotas.txt
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%B IN (C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\cpu.txt) DO echo %%B >> C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\cpufiltruotas.txt
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%B IN (C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\ramvid.txt) DO echo %%B >> C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\ramvidfiltruotas.txt

for /F %%a in (C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\ramvidfiltruotas.txt) do set /a c+=%%a echo %c% >> C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\naujas.txt
```

I am trying to calculate the sum of numbers that are in file `ramvidfiltruotas.txt`, but when I start the script it shows me a lot of this:

```
C:\Users\Diana>set /a c+=3472 echo   1>>C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\naujas.txt
Missing operator.

C:\Users\Diana>set /a c+=2616 echo   1>>C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\naujas.txt
Missing operator.
```

Maybe someone could help me to find the problem here?

By the way, this script works on other computer.

Comment: `echo` is imo not a valid [operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two commands running together.  Either separate the `set` and `echo` on different lines, or concatenate them with an ampersand `&`:

```
set /a c+=2616 & echo   1>>C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\naujas.txt
```

Comment: No it didn't! Look again... Well, it `did` fix the `missing operator` problem - but `set /a c+=%%a echo %c% ...` won't work as expected in a `for` loop. The `ORIGINAL` value of `c` will be reported, not the `augmented` value. If you want to output the `changed` value, you'd need to use `!c!` not `%c%`

Comment: Peter, i am not so good in english, can you please explain the difference between ORIGINAL and AUGMENTED values?

Comment: Peter is right - by AUGMENTED he means accumulated, the result of your += operations.